# Contact Form error message not visible in component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, extract-error-message

I have a ContactForm component which takes in Message, email and name inputs and uses sendgrid to send an email.

On succcess the success message is shown properly but the error is not showing up in the componenet.

here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { emailContactForm } from "../../actions/form";

const ContactForm = ({ authorEmail }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    message: "",
    name: "",
    email: "",
    sent: false,
    buttonText: "Send Message",
    success: false,
    error: false,
  });

  const { message, name, email, sent, buttonText, success, error } = values;

  const clickSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, buttonText: "Sending..." });
    emailContactForm({ authorEmail, name, email, message }).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          sent: true,
          name: "",
          email: "",
          message: "",
          buttonText: "Sent",
          success: data.success,
        });
      }
    });
  };

  const handleChange = (name) => (e) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: e.target.value,
      error: false,
      success: false,
      buttonText: "Send Message",
    });
  };

  const showSuccessMessage = () =>
    success && (
      <div className="alert alert-info">Thank you for contacting us.</div>
    );

  const showErrorMessage = () => (
    <div
      className="alert alert-danger"
      style={{ display: error ? "" : "none" }}
    >
      {error}
    </div>
  );

  const contactForm = () => {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={clickSubmit} className="pb-5">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="lead">Message</label>
          <textarea
            onChange={handleChange("message")}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={message}
            required
            rows="10"
          ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="lead">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange("name")}
            className="form-control"
            value={name}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="lead">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            onChange={handleChange("email")}
            className="form-control"
            value={email}
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary">{buttonText}</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      {showSuccessMessage()}
      {showErrorMessage()}
      {contactForm()}
    </>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

On getting error the message is not showing up

On Success:
[Succes Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzLVD.png)
[success message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYGRG.png)

Error code that is shown in console:
[Error Response Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzLVD.png)

[Error response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6whp.png)

Comment: did you try `emailForm(...).then(data => {...}).catch(error => setValues({ ...values, error: data.error }))`

Comment: I tried it with no change

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you handle fetch errors in a `catch` block, like this:

```
emailContactForm({ authorEmail, name, email, message }).then((data) => {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          sent: true,
          name: "",
          email: "",
          message: "",
          buttonText: "Sent",
          success: data.success,
        });
      }
    }).catch(error => {
          setValues({ ...values, error });
    });
```

Also try to change the css for `display` like so:

```
const showErrorMessage = () => (
    <div
      className="alert alert-danger"
      style={{ display: error ? "block" : "none" }}
    >
      {error}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Tried it but still giving the same response code and no error message visible